# Assignment to integer pointer causes a crash

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a simple program like :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
*(int*) 1 = 1;
return 0;
}
```

but why it is giving me Segmentation fault?

Comment: Are you asking whether it causes a crash? It probably does.

Comment: What was the idea (goal) of this assignment? Your program tries to write in a very wrong place, so it must crash.

Comment: I was trying to write a program that would create a corefile without using any built in funtions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will most likely crash no most systems. The assignment

```
*(int*)1 = 1;
```

tries to assign 1 to the location in memory with address 1. This is very undefined behaviour, and in most of systems the memory protection mechanism raises an error when you try it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to write to memory with address 0x01.

A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access.